# Converting JSON file to Table format using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, tabular

I want to create multiple tables depending on the number of objects available for me let me give an example the JSON data is

```
{
"data": [
{
  "name": "Contest",
  "value": "Contest"
},
{
  "name": "State",
  "value": "State"
},
{
  "name": "County",
  "value": "County"
},
{
  "name": "Election Date",
  "value": "Election_Date"
}
],
"metadata": [
{
  "1": {
    "name": "name",
    "type": "text"
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "value",
    "type": "text"
  }
},
{
  "rows": 4
}
],
"lastModified": 1492072490000
}
```

I found a solution online but I was unable to implement using Javascript if anyone can give me any suggestions you are most welcome. 
The website is http://json2table.com/

Comment: you want to write javascript code to generate table similar to that one that you get pasting this json to that page?

Comment: yes i want to create table similar to that

Comment: can you give us code of what have you tried so far?